# Order array of sentences by an array containing words / searchterms

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sql-order-by

I have an array of sentences that I retrieve from an MYSQL database based on an array of words:

```
$queryTitles = '
    SELECT title
    FROM `#__items`
    WHERE `title` REGEXP "'.$search.'" AND `published`=1';
```

Where $search contains the REGEXP:

```
foreach ($searchword as $key => $value) {

        if ($key === array_key_last($searchword)) {
            $search .= '' . $db->escape( $value, true ) . '';
            break;
        }
        
        $search = '' . $db->escape( $value, true ) . '|';

        
    }
```

Now I get this list of titles back which contains the words in the $search words. But I'd like to order these list of titles based on the amounts of words found in the array.. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Maybe with usort?

```
usort($dataCat, function ($a, $b) {

        $countA=0;
        $countB=0;
        foreach ($searchword as $value) {
           if(checkIfContains($a, $value )){
            $countA++;
           }
           if(checkIfContains($a, $value )){
            $countB++;
           }
        }
        
        if ($countA == $countB) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($countA < $countB) ? -1 : 1;

    });
```

But this doesn't work... Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Security note: don't  write queries this way. [Prepare your statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), never use plain string composition.

Comment: If that's the exact code, you should have a Warning somewhere: `$searchword` is not in scope inside the `usort` callback. You need to "capture" it with `function ($a, $b) use ( $searchword ) { ... }`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I escape the values right?

Comment: I don't know which `escape` function you're using, but even if you think you wrote safe statements, unless you use prepared statements (which lets the _database_ apply the safe-making-rules based on what it knows about your table schemas) you're not really guaranteeing safe data handling.

Comment: Ok thanks will change it

Comment: *"But this doesn't work.."* ... Take a look at your 2nd condition in your usort: It checks for "a" but increments "b". Also without seeing your `checkIfContains()` function, can't verify here if thats correct.